# How to add a vibrance value to a render in post processing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, node-editor, compositing-nodes

Is there a way in Blender to add vibrance?  I have a render which I'm trying to add vibrance to in Blender, not in Photoshop (which is what I've been doing, but is tedious).

I know there is a saturation node, but vibrance is usually thought to be more practical.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33966821/6773916 - untimately essentially anything photoshop can do can be done in Blender - though sometimes you’ll have to resort to raw maths nodes or scripting. Can you define precisely what you mean by ‘Vibrance’? Can you provide some examples?

Comment: related: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9398/is-there-an-equivalent-to-adobes-vibrance-in-gimp

Answer (score -1):

go to compositing.
turn on show nodes.
press shift+A.
search hue.
it will come up.

Comment: *"Saturation boosts all colours by the same amount whilst vibrance aims to boost the least saturated colours whilst leaving already saturated colours where they are."* from: https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/9386